# htaccess show error page without change url when extension page is php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, custom-error-pages

I hide the extension of the pages using .htaccess file. 
Example: page contact.php will show contact/

I use this code:

```
Options -MultiViews<br>
RewriteEngine On<br>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f<br>
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php [L]<br>
```

How can I show the costum error page 404 when, in the url, I write the name of the page with the extension without change the url?

Example: 
contact.php -> Error
contact/ -> Ok

Now, if the url contains a page with the extension, I see a page, but i don't want. I want to see the page without extension and in case contains the extension, show the error page.

Someone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: Rewrite internally the request to your custom error page.

Comment: I resolved setting the page 404 with an absolute url.